# How to supply a large data set of numbers to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, json

I will need to supply a large data set consisting of numbers to a algorithm written in JavaScript. It will do some calculations and store the output in variables. The data-set will have around 1000 numbers and I will have multiple data set which will I will select using buttons on the screen.

I have been suggested to use JSON files. I am implementing an AV voting system so a voter would have to rank their vote in preference. Meaning that Voter 1 will have multiple votes which will need to be parsed.

Any ideas on how to supply these numbers?

Comment: are you loading in the data asynchronously? like with a web-service? if so, you could have the server spit back a JSONP response (a JSON data object inside a callback function) or, you could have it just return a bit of JS that already has the data parsed out into an array or object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like they are static. If so:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
algorithm(numbers);
```

Using javascript files

Comment: That is a way however there will be potentially thousands of numbers. I am implementing an AV voting system so a voter would have to rank their vote in preference. Meaning that Voter 1 will have multiple votes which will need to be parsed.  I should edit the question to include this. Sorry.